# Combining for each statements

Tags: powershell, for-loop, active-directory

I am trying to get the count of computers in each active directory OU which I am able to do. I am also trying to get the count of computers in each OU that belong to the Test_Group (P) membership group which I can do as well. I just don't know how to output both on the same line? So I would like to select name, computer, then the value of $Test as well? Below is an example of what I trying to achieve, right now I can only get the name and computers to output?

Name  Computers  Test

US       100             3

CA        20              1

```
import-module activedirectory
 foreach ($ou in  Get-ADOrganizationalUnit  -filter * -SearchScope 1){
   $computers = 0 + (get-adcomputer -filter * -searchbase $ou.distinguishedname).count 
     $Test =  (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity “Test_Group (P)”).count 
     $ou | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name Computers -value $computers -force
     $ou | select name,computers

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try this one:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
foreach($ou in Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchScope 1){
    $computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $ou.DistinguishedName -Properties 'memberof'
    [int]$numComputers = $computers.count
    [int]$numMemberOfTestGroup = ($computers | Where-Object {$_.memberof -match 'TEST_Group (P)'}).count
    Write-Output ([PSCustomObject] @{
        OU = $ou.Name
        NumComputers = $numComputers
        NumTestMembers = $numMemberOfTestGroup
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to be what I need but all the values are 0? One of the OU's should have a value of 3 for "NumTestMembers" For some reason it is not giving the correct output

Comment: hmm.. strange.. I tried it with a single ou and single group at my end and got the correct values. Is NumComputers 0 as well?

Comment: Also.. try get Get-ADComputer command manually against one OU and verify that you in fact get the memberof property populated with data

Comment: NumComputers is correct, I tried with other groups as well and its always 0. Not sure what it could be?

Comment: Missed a } in the code. Try now. Hopefully that was it.

Comment: Unfortunately still all 0's even after I fixed it. When I ran the get-adcomputer for a machine it didn't show me all the properties maybe that's why>

Comment: Could it be a permission problem? The only reason for NumTestMembers to always return 0 is for '$computers | Where-Object {$_.memberof -match 'TEST_Group (P)'}' to always return 0. So you need to make sure that you actually get data in the memberof property and that the match is working.

Comment: That's what it was thank you very much for your help

Comment: Np. Hopefully you will sort it out. Btw. you could replace the -match '' with -like '' if you want to. With -like you could use wildcard *. For example: {$_.memberof -like '*TEST*'}